# Null values at the end of rows after INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, insert, sql-insert

I am currently trying to `INSERT INTO` my SQL database a row of 144 columns.
The problem is that the last 10 values of the new row are NULL while they are supposed to be float and int.

That's an example of what I have in my DB after the `INSERT INTO` :

| First column | Before last column | Last column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |

That's the SQL request I am using

```
INSERT INTO "historic_data2" 
VALUES (28438, 163, 156, 1, 'FIST 2', 91, 81, 82, 84, 90, 6, '2 Pts Int M', 'Offensive', 0, '91_81_82_84_90', 86, 85, 0, 36, 62, 24, 0, 132, 86, 0, 83, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 77, 24, 0, 173, 107, 0, 204, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42, 77, 24, 0, 173, 107, 0, 204, 0, 0, 0, 81, 62, 34, 23, 19, 45, 32, 18, 9, 19, 0.5555555555555556, 0.5161290322580645, 0.5294117647058824, 0.391304347826087, 1.0, 82, 54, 34, 18, 28, 49, 27, 17, 8, 28, 0.5975609756097561, 0.5, 0.5, 0.4444444444444444, 1.0, 302, 233, 132, 89, 69, 168, 116, 69, 35, 69, 0.5562913907284768, 0.4978540772532189, 0.5227272727272727, 0.39325842696629215, 1.0, 214, 161, 84, 73, 53, 119, 79, 39, 36, 53, 0.5560747663551402, 0.4906832298136646, 0.4642857142857143, 0.4931506849315068, 1.0, 717, 544, 298, 233, 173, 416, 285, 175, 97, 173, 0.5801952580195258, 0.5238970588235294, 0.587248322147651, 0.41630901287553645, 1.0, 466, 315, 183, 128, 151, 357, 233, 138, 91, 151, 0.7660944206008584, 0.7396825396825397, 0.7540983606557377, 0.7109375,1.0,112)
```

I can't figure out how to solve this issue. My guess would be that there is a hard limit on how much column you can insert at once but I don't know how to solve that.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You simply don't have enough values in the `values()` list.  I would suggest that you list the columns explicitly in the `insert` so you can see the error that the numbers mismatch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response, it makes a lot of sense. 
I'll have a look